# Angular2 Bind Attribute Value

Tags: data-binding, attributes, angular

Similar to [Angular2 two-way data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468290/angular2-two-way-data-binding), I have a parent and a child component. In the parent I change the value that is passed to the child component via property. The property of the child is named `percentage`.

https://gist.github.com/ideadapt/59c96d01bacbf3222096

I want to bind the property value to a html attribute value. Like: <div style="width: {{percentage}}%">. I didn't find any syntax that worked. So I ended up using a change listener that does some manual DOM update:

```
this.progressElement = DOM.querySelector(element.nativeElement, '.progress');
DOM.setAttribute(this.progressElement, "style", `width: ${this.percentage}%`);
```

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `NgStyle`, which works similar to Angular 1. Since [alpha-30](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha30-2015-07-07), NgStyle is available in `angular2/directives`:

```
import {NgStyle} from 'angular2/directives';
```

Then include `NgStyle` in the directives list, this should work ([here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ab3f2365fd8e723dd2af40c04d729ee30bcc04d8/modules/angular2/test/directives/ng_style_spec.ts) are some examples):

```
@View({
    directives: [NgStyle]
    template: `
        <div class="all">
            <div class="progress" [ng-style]="{'width': percentage + '%'}"></div>
            <span class="label">{{percentage}}</span>
        </div>
    `
})
```

Alternatively and without using `NgStyle`, this would work well too:

```
<div class="progress" [style.width]="percentage + '%'"></div>
```

Comment: we should use [style.width.px] or some units indicator

Answer (score 64):

You can use **percentage binding** for CSS properties: `[style.width.%]`

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'progress-bar',
    template: `
        <div class="progress-bar">
            <div [style.width.%]="value"> {{ value }}% </div>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class ProgressBar {
    @Input() private value: number;
}
```