# Angular two way data binding in child component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do two way databinding using the banana in box sytax, and I need to pass a value down to a component (compone) then to another component (comptwo) where it will be edited.

My expectation was that the binding will enable the changes to be reflected in the app.component. However, I'm unable to do this.

I've used the example from this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39943256/3836415) response, although it is not the voted answer to the question. I've seen this being represented in other blogs.

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-va12nw) of my issue. I'm just after help and possible explanation of what I'm doing wrong ?

**Edited :** to include code snippets from stackblitz:

*App.Component.ts*

```
export class AppComponent  {
  public _Name = 'Angular';  
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
From app.component.html : {{_Name}}
```

*compone.component.ts*

```
...
public _Name:string = "";
@Output() NameChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
@Input()
set Name(value:string)
{

  this._Name = value;
  this.NameChange.emit(value);

}
get Name():string
{
  return this._Name;

}
...
```

*compone.component.html*

```
...
<p>
compone works!
<app-comptwo [(Name)]="_Name"></app-comptwo>
{{_Name}}
</p>
...
```

*comptwo.component.ts*

```
...
public _Name:string = "";
@Output() NameChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
@Input()
set Name(value:string)
{

  this._Name = value;
  this.NameChange.emit(value);

}
get Name():string
{
  return this._Name;

}
...
```

*comptwo.component.html*

```
...
<p>
comptwo works! <input [(ngModel)]="_Name">
{{_Name}}
</p>
...
```

As it can be seen above, app.component is where the field originates from. It is passed into compone, and then into comptwo. Comptwo component is where the field is being modified via an input tag.

Comment: Although you provided stackblitz which is very good also please provide some code here

Comment: Hi good point, I avoided adding the code here because at times StackOverflow complains that there is more code than an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using setter/getter, you have to bind events to them (in this case `Name`, not directly to model field (`_Name`). Getters/setters wont be called otherwise if you are binding to private `_Field`  as you are literally bypassing setters.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awlpfh

Result of using propert bindings:

[image]

**Edited:**

compone.component.html is altered from :

```
<app-comptwo [(Name)]="_Name"></app-comptwo>
```

to this:

```
<app-comptwo [(Name)]="Name"></app-comptwo>
```

Comment: what file contains the changed code? i am curious about how this works.

Comment: template files.

Comment: ah, ok. i see the difference in `compone.component.html` and `comptwo.component.html`. thank you!

Comment: Since it solves the issue, you can mark it as acceppted.

Comment: Hi @Antoniossss thanks for your help with this. So as I understand the in Compone template you are using the Input set/get (<app-comptwo [(Name)]="Name"></app-comptwo>) from Compone instead of the model field. Do you know of any resources that goes in depth into how this is all working - I'm still struggling to understand the roles of the getter/setter and EventEmitter.

Comment: Hi I hope you don't mind I've updated your response with the code snippet of the changes. This was based on the comment by @RezaRahmati on the question.

Comment: Angular tutorials are great explanation of how binding works. This is kind of straight forward - you wrote your event broadcast logic in setter methods, but you bypasses it setting value of field directly. Im glad you are on the right track now.